# How to make a navigation graph for bottom navigation ? and is there a way to modify the back stack behavior?

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-architecture-navigation

I'm new to the navigation architecture component and am trying to make a `bottom navigation` view. I'm really confused about how should I implement my navigation graph the right way. In addition, I want to make the back stack gets back to the "home" fragment then exists instead of navigating all the back stack.

My app consists of three fragments for bottom navigation. What I've tried to do that I've linked the fragments in every possible combination in the graph.
The result was not catastrophic but am still not sure if this is the right way to do it.
In addition, when am using the back button of the device the app navigates through every single fragment I've navigated through before exiting the app.

I want to make the navigation so that for the first back button, it navigates back to the first fragment - the start point - then for the second one exists the app.

Here's the code of the navigation graph

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/nav_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/bottom_navigation_home">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation_home"
        android:name="com.app.albaladinn.view.ui.HomeFragment"
        android:label="fragment_home"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_homeFragment_to_couponsFragment"
            app:destination="@id/bottom_navigation_coupons" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_homeFragment_to_settingsFragment"
            app:destination="@id/bottom_navigation_settings" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_homeFragment_to_categoriesFragment"
            app:destination="@id/bottom_navigation_categories" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation_coupons"
        android:name="com.app.albaladinn.view.ui.CouponsFragment"
        android:label="fragment_coupons"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_coupons" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_couponsFragment_to_homeFragment"
            app:destination="@id/bottom_navigation_home" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_couponsFragment_to_settingsFragment"
            app:destination="@id/bottom_navigation_settings" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_couponsFragment_to_categoriesFragment"
            app:destination="@id/bottom_navigation_categories" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation_settings"
        android:name="com.app.albaladinn.view.ui.SettingsFragment"
        android:label="fragment_settings"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_settings" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_settingsFragment_to_couponsFragment"
            app:destination="@id/bottom_navigation_coupons" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_settingsFragment_to_homeFragment"
            app:destination="@id/bottom_navigation_home" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_settingsFragment_to_categoriesFragment"
            app:destination="@id/bottom_navigation_categories" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation_categories"
        android:name="com.app.albaladinn.view.ui.CategoriesFragment"
        android:label="fragment_categories"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_categories">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_categoriesFragment_to_couponsFragment"
            app:destination="@id/bottom_navigation_coupons" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_categoriesFragment_to_homeFragment"
            app:destination="@id/bottom_navigation_home"
            app:popUpToInclusive="false" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_categoriesFragment_to_settingsFragment"
            app:destination="@id/bottom_navigation_settings" />
    </fragment>
</navigation>
```

and here's the main activity

```
public class MainNavigationActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    BottomNavigationView mainBottomNavigation;
    MainBottomNavigationControl mainBottomNavigationControl;
    NavController navController;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_navigation);
        navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.frame_container);
        mainBottomNavigation = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(mainBottomNavigation, navController);
        mainBottomNavigationControl = new MainBottomNavigationControl();
        mainBottomNavigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mainBottomNavigationControl);
    }

    class MainBottomNavigationControl implements 
            BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.bottom_navigation_home:
                    navController.navigate(R.id.bottom_navigation_home);
                    return true;
                case R.id.bottom_navigation_categories:
                    navController.navigate(R.id.bottom_navigation_categories);
                    return true;
                case R.id.bottom_navigation_coupons:
                    navController.navigate(R.id.bottom_navigation_coupons);
                    return true;
                case R.id.bottom_navigation_settings:
                    navController.navigate(R.id.bottom_navigation_settings);
                    return true;
                default:
                    return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `fragmentManager?.popBackStack()` will return to previous fragment

Comment: I know how to use FragmentManager, I want to totaly do it using NavigationUI or the navigation graph or smth. Isn't there a way to do it using the new arch. component ?

Comment: When first button is clicked, you want it back to `startDestination` ?

Comment: If you're using `NavigationUI` as per [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#bottom_navigation), you'll be getting your expected behavior already. Please include your code and navigation graph.

Comment: Say for example I opened the app, navigated to the second  fragment then to the third then back to the second. When I use the back button it navigates me back in the reverse order of all the actions I've done.

Comment: @ianhanniballake edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(mainBottomnavigation, navController)` **already** creates the proper `OnNavigationItemSelectedListener` for you, so you should remove your `MainBottomNavigationControl` entirely - it is unneeded.

Comment: Yes, that fixes the problem, thanks.
any ideas about the graph ?

Comment: You wouldn't need any of the actions you've specified to get bottom nav working, so they can all be deleted.

Comment: @ianhanniballake but this would mean that if he navigated to a tab which is not startDestination in that graph, then the back button would take him back to startDestination, not the home/login activity. How would you fix that?

Comment: @Lurr - as per the [Principles of Navigation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-principles#fixed_start_destination), you should always be exiting your activity via the start destination of your graph and this is an assumption that NavigationUI makes.

Comment: @ianhanniballake setupWithNavController works great with ui navigation graph with same ids but how restrict to not create already selected fragment any idea?

Comment: @SohailZahid - if you mean on reselecting a tab, BottomNavigationView has a separate reselected listener you can set (and have it do nothing for instance)

Comment: Any idea how to implement bottomnavview in the fragment working with nav graph?